# Discord.js v14 - isJSONEncodable issue on Embed message/interaction reply

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I am using Discord.js v14.8 and it was written in typescript i have package:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/rest": "^1.1.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.25.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.14",
    "discord.js": "14.8.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "discord-api-types": "0.37.20"
  }
```

I am having issues with my `/help` or even at normal command `!help`, i will show you the `/help` command code:

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder, ChannelType, TextChannel, EmbedBuilder } from "discord.js"
import { getThemeColor } from "../functions";
import { SlashCommand } from "../types";

const command : SlashCommand = {
    command: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("help")
    .setDescription("Shows the information about the bot")
    ,
    execute: interaction => {
        interaction.reply({
            embeds: [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                .setAuthor({name: "XXX.XX", iconURL: "https://i.imgur.com/XXXX.png"})
                .setTitle("XXXX")
                .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/XXX.png")
                .setColor(getThemeColor("text"))
                .setDescription(
                    "discord bot developed by <@XXXXXXXXX>."
                )
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Application Commands', value: '`/help`, `/XXX`, `/xxx`, `/xx`, `/xx`' },
                )
                .setTimestamp()
                .setImage("https://i.imgur.com/XXXXX.png")
                .setFooter({ text: "Powered by XXXX", iconURL: interaction.client.user?.avatarURL() || undefined })
                
            ]
        })
    },
    cooldown: 30
}

export default command
```

and this is the output error:

```js
this is the error:
/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessagePayload.js:200
        isJSONEncodable(embed) ? embed.toJSON() : this.target.client.options.jsonTransformer(embed),
        ^
TypeError: isJSONEncodable is not a function
    at /home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessagePayload.js:200:9
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MessagePayload.resolveBody (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessagePayload.js:199:36)
    at TextChannel.send (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:169:32)
    at Message.reply (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:803:25)
    at /home/container/build/commands/help
.js:17:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/container/build/commands/help.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/container/build/commands/help.js:4:12)
```

but this one works fine which is the `/ping` command:

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder, ChannelType, TextChannel, EmbedBuilder } from "discord.js"
import { getThemeColor } from "../functions";
import { SlashCommand } from "../types";

const command : SlashCommand = {
    command: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Shows the bot ping/latency.")
    ,
    execute: interaction => {
        interaction.reply({
            embeds: [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                .setAuthor({name: "Test"})
                .setDescription(` Ping: ${interaction.client.ws.ping}ms`)
                .setColor(getThemeColor("text"))
            ]
        })
    },
    cooldown: 30
}

export default command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed on Discord.js 14.10.2